# On adding a new Cassandra node, existing role cannot login into the node

Tags: cassandra

A new Cassandra node (let's call it `c3`) was introduced into our cluster, into a datacenter which already had 2 other nodes (`c1` and `c2`). `nodetool repair` was performed within the datacenter after the node joined the ring.

`nodetool status` reports that the new node has indeed joined the cluster, in the same datacenter.

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                         Rack
UN  xx.xx.xx.c1   48.47 GiB  256          71.0%             5908eee6-63e9-464e-9d65-b20a5f46c86c  rack1
UN  xx.xx.xx.c2   58.11 GiB  256          64.0%             28691036-3e11-49e9-83d6-9bbe577f7249  rack1
UN  xx.xx.xx.c3   37.7 GiB   256          65.0%             c8a3e0a3-0dc9-4951-b9c5-ee32dc7a12fd  rack1
```

A `role` called *analytics* existed in the cluster before the introduction of the new node. Our Spark jobs use this role to write data into the Cassandra cluster (via Datastax Spark-Cassandra Connector).

Post the addition of the new node, I am observing the following two exceptions in my logs:

`java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to reports.ts_table. The latest exception was User analytics has no MODIFY permission on <table reports.ts_table> or any of its parents. 
Please check the executor logs for more exceptions and information at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(TableWriter.scala:243) ...`

`Cluster: Authentication error during reconnection to /xx.xx.xx.c3:9042, scheduling retry in 16000 milliseconds.
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /xx.xx.xx.c3:9042: Username and/or password are incorrect`

These exceptions seem to occur only when the write goes to the newly added `c3` node.
Multiple repairs on `system_auth` schema alone, and full repairs of the datacenter does not seem to fix this. The replication factor of `system_auth` schema for the datacenter is 2.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good to increase the RF of system_auth to 3 in your case after new node joined.

So do the following

> 1. ALTER system_auth keypsace RF to 3 for the DC
> 2. RUN repair -full system_auth

Comment: Thank you for your response, Laxmikant. I will try this approach & report back.

Comment: Would you suggest increasing the RF for the other system schemas: `system_traces` and `system_distributed` as well ? I could not locate any literature (docs, SO posts) on this at all. Do you have any references? @Laxmikant

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thank you. I changed the RF for each of the system schemas.